"-I noticed a crack in the wall. -I did so too." — Is "did" an auxiliary or lexical verb here? Is "so" a direct object or an adjunct?
my conclusions from a topic on ell.stackexchange.com:
-I noticed a crack in the wall.
-I did too. — (correct because "did" is an auxiliary here and, therefore, has no lexical meaning)
-I did it too. — (incorrect because "did" is a lexical verb here; the verb "notice" means such an action which cannot be described with the lexical verb "do")
-I did so too. — (correct because "did so" means "noticed a crack") (sounds formal)
I'm very interested in:
Is "did" in "I did so too" an auxiliary or lexical verb?
Is "so" in "I did so too" a direct object or an adjunct?

Merriam-Webster says "so" is a pronoun in "if you have to file a claim, do so as soon as possible" (and hence functioning as a noun). But this (citing Carl Bache) claims "so" is an adverb in "I don't think so". So it's probably debatable, but interested to see the theories.

@StuartF Do I understand correctly that if we consider "so" as a pronoun, then "did" is a lexical verb, but if we consider "so" as an adverb, then "did" is an auxiliary ? Thanks.

This is a cross-posting which is frowned on around here. Just letting you know. As I explained on ELL, if you have "so", "did" is lexical. I did so. means I did it.

@Lambie Where's the cross-posting? I can't see the duplicate anywhere on ELL.

@Araucaria-Him https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/357881/what-verb-phrases-can-i-replace-with-do-it-or-do-that-e-g-i-noticed-a-s/357886#357886

@Lambie That's not even vaguely a dupe!

@Araucaria-Him You must be kidding. In fact, I was the one who posted the idea of lexical versus auxiliary verb which the OP then takes up in comments in that post and then again here. And you will notice that all the OP does is argue with me. :) I noticed the crack in the wall and all the list of responses are exactly what is in the other question. [exclamation mark]. It's not a dupe. It's a reworded cross posting using what I contributed...

@Lambie The lexical/auxiliary verb issue has been a theme of several of OP's interesting questions before and after your linked-to answer. However, in the case which you believe is identical the verb has a DO, which it doesn't here. In fact your answer there already skews the issue, because  it ignores the fact that there's a D.O. in OPs example, as if it wasn't a significant factor, when it is a most significant factor indeed. Actually it's the significant factor. The sentence "I did it too" is completely unlike "I did too" in relation to OP's concerns.

I'm not entirely sure why 'the verb "notice" meaning such an action which cannot be described with the lexical verb "do"' would apply to 'I did it too', but not 'I did so too'. To me, both sound equally wrong.

@Araucaria-Him It did it too. is lexical. I did too. is not. It's an auxiliary. I think I have now said it three times? Auxiliaries don't take direct objects.

@Araucaria-Him From my answer on ELL: Did you do your homework? Yes, I did. [auxiliary do]
Did you do your homework? Yes, I did it. is for a lexical use of the verb do.
Did you do your homework? No, not yet. But I will do so. do so replaces do homework. [lexical]
